# How to setup default interlacing for PNGs in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png

Every time I want to save a PNG in photoshop, asks me what type of interlacing I want.  Is it possible to set the default to None and never hear about that dialog box again?

Comment: What version of Photoshop?

Comment: Adobe Photoshop cs4 - latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use "Save As" for PNGs. It generates needlessly large files. If you want all metadata PS puts when "Saving as", you could just save it as PSD.

Use "Save for web". It will give you more reasonable size. Still, you'll get a window before saving, but at least it will be a little more useful than just interlace yes/no question.